# Where to write Django custom validator

Tags: django, django-models

Where exactly I have to write the custom validators in Django folder?

Below is the folder where I have my models
/home/shrivatsa555/childrenGK/cgkapp/models.py

I have to validate the question difficulty level in the range of 1, 2 and 3 only:

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    Question_Number = models.AutoField(primary_key = True),
    Question_Text = models.CharField(max_length = 1000),
    Option1 = models.CharField(max_length=500),
    Option2 = models.CharField(max_length=500),
    Option3 = models.CharField(max_length=500),
    Option4 = models.CharField(max_length=500),
    Answer = models.CharField(max_length=500),
    Difficulty_Level = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_number])
```

I have written a custom validator in the views.py but its not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 3 ways, that i know at least:

1. Create a validators.py file and import your validators in models and use them likes this:

   ```
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[validate_title])
   ```
2. Create a validators.py file and import your validators in forms and use them like this:

   ```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].validators.append(validate_title)
   ```
3. You can create custom clean() form method and use your validator here:

   ```
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(IceCreamOrderForm, self).clean()
        title = cleaned_data.get('title', '')
        if title in x:
            msg = '...'
            raise forms.ValidationError(msg)
        return cleaned_data
   ```

Comment: many thanks my validator has from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_number(value):
    if value not in [1, 2, 3]:
        raise ValidationError('%s Value Not between 1-3 ' % value) and when I use in the models as     Difficulty_Level = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_number]) giving error undefined name validate_number

Comment: did you imported validate_number in models?

Comment: yes but the syntax was wrong I imported with from cgkapp import validators instead of from cgkapp.validators import validate_number.. thank you.. Now its working..

Comment: How can validate a field which depends on other field i.e; if I want validate a ip field whether it comes under same network (which we put in network field)???